# MySQL is adding characters to my data

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I have a Table in MySQL and I am adding data to it from a csv file

My code is:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/myaddress/file.csv'
INTO TABLE db.mytable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(`Currency`,`field2`,`field3`)
```

This loads fine except for the first row I add.

I'm adding a `USD` but when I do a query it imports it as `ï»¿USD`.
This only happens for the first row. Anybody knows why this happens?

Solution:
This is an encoding issue, so to solve it, here are two options

1.- Encode the file differently

2.- Add a dummy line and use `IGNORE 1 LINES`

Comment: There is a tick missing after 'field3. Is it missed in your sql script too? Perhaps it excapes your first rows data.

Comment: ok. u updated. `LOAD DATA INFILE '/blah/blah/file.csv' INTO TABLE test IGNORE 1 LINES;`  .... keep that in your arsenal. is that first row `column info` (i am sure you would say no). it is hard to tell without looking at your csv

Comment: I didn't have headers on my file. I added a header row and used the ignore. I actually works now. Weird. Thanks

Comment: yea i say yea so my word count is allowed yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is something related with your csv. It has been encoded with  UTF-8 BOM in ISO-8859-1 (spanish?).

If you are using a editor like Notepad++ open your csv and select from the top menu -> Encoding -> utf-8 without DOM , save and try again.

Comment: use comments above for questions